matplotlib Zoom - Modify "Zoom to Rectangle" button to always zoom to a square
I am having a really hard time with Matplotlib when using set_aspect('equal') as per this question
I am trying an alternative to this problem. Is there a way for me to modify "Zoom to rectangle" button such that it always zooms to a "square" ? What I meant is, when I use the zoom function and select a rectangle, I want the rectangle automatically change to a squire such that the present aspect ratio is preserved
Can this be done ?
